# Is Federation ID Predicate just a SQL Azure thing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, federation

Im setting up a multi tenant database and came across the following blog post on federations: [SQL Azure Multi Tenant](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbiyikoglu/archive/2011/03/23/moving-to-multi-tenant-model-made-easy-with-sql-azure-federations.aspx)

They write about assigning a predicate to filter data between tenants:

> In a single-tenant app, the query logic in application is coded with the assumption that all data in a database belongs to one tenant. With multi-tenant apps that work with identical schemas, refactored code simply injects tenant_id into the schema (tables, indexes etc) and every query the app issues, contains the tenant_id=? predicate. In a federation, where tenant_id is the federation key, you are asked to still implement the schema changes. However federations provide a connection type called a FILTERING connection that automatically injects this tenant_id predicate without requiring app refactoring. Our data-dependent routing sets up a FILTERING connection by default. Here is how;

1: USE FEDERATION orders_federation(tenant_id=155) WITH RESET, FILTERING=ON

My question is, is this just a SQL azure thing? Or can this be accomplished with any sql server instance?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Federations are available only on SQL Azure.